# Javascript Create Dynamic Object Class

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**JS TOOLS**

Angular 1.5.x & lodash 4.x

**QUESTION**

I’m trying to create an object factory pattern that creates object / classes . In my example below I’m create object models for content types e.g. Article, Document, Images, etc. Given my skill limitations I’m replicating the Article example below for every content type. Is there a way in JavaScript to create a dynamic object class with a unique prototype.

*CURRENT APPROACH*

```
 // constructor injection
_Constructor.$inject = [];
function _Constructor() {
    function __constructor(data, keys) {
        _.assign(this, _.pick(data, keys));
    }
    return __constructor;
}

// one of many content type models
Article.$inject = ['__constructor'];
function Article(__constructor) {
    function Article(data) {
        var fillables = Object.freeze(['id','title','subtitle','body','body']);
        __constructor.call(this, data, fillables);
    }

    Article.prototype = Object.create(__constructor.prototype);
    Article.prototype.constructor = Article;
    return Article;
}
```

**IDEAL OUTCOME**

Create a content type model factory pattern that allows me to create unique content type object models. Pseudo example:

```
var documentFillables =  Object.freeze(['id', 'name', 'body']),
    documentData = {id:1,name:'My Document', body: 'coolbody stuff'},
    Document = new ModelFactory('Document', documentData, documentFillables),
    articleFillables =  Object.freeze(['id', 'title', 'subtitle']),
    articleData = {id:1,title:'My Article', subtitle: 'My Subtitle'},
    Article = new ModelFactory('Article', articleData, articleFillables);
```

Note I've played around with merge, extend and clone and although I can replicate and extend objects I end up with a fair amount of code redundancy and/or generic objects i.e. have many `ModelFactory()` but no `Article()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a service (a factory that is returning a constructor function) that is common to all of your document types.

Inside of that function you can use `angular.extend` to extend the default values with your passed data.

Also take care to the naming e.g. don't use `document` to avoid naming conflicts with the browsers document object. That's why I named it `myDocument`.

To create extended factories you can use dependency injection in the factory function and extend the base (see code for `imageService` as an example).

Please have a look at the demo below or in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/9a6jhw47/).

```js
angular.module('demoApp', [])
  .factory('content', ContentService)
  .factory('article', ContentService)
  .factory('myDocument', ContentService)
  .factory('myImage', imageService)
  .controller('mainController', MainController);

function MainController(article, myDocument, myImage) {
  console.log(new article({
    title: 'Test'
  }));
  console.log(new myDocument({
    title: 'second'
  }));
  console.log(new myImage({
    title: 'image'
  }));
  var newImage = new myImage({
    title: 'placeholder img',
    src: 'https://placehold.it/300'
  });
  console.log(newImage);

  this.newImage = newImage;
}

function generateUUID() {
  var d = new Date().getTime();
  if (window.performance && typeof window.performance.now === "function") {
    d += performance.now(); //use high-precision timer if available
  }
  var uuid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
    var r = (d + Math.random() * 16) % 16 | 0;
    d = Math.floor(d / 16);
    return (c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8)).toString(16);
  });
  return uuid;
}

/*
// base not really needed, just as example
function base(options) {
 angular.extend(this, {
        id: generateUUID(),
        title: '',
        subtitle: '',
        body: ''
    }, options);
}*/

function ContentService() {
  return function(options) {
    //base.call(this, options);
    angular.extend(this, {
      id: generateUUID(),
      title: '',
      subtitle: '',
      body: ''
    }, options);
  };
}

function imageService(content, $window) {

  return function(options) {
    var contentFactory = new content(options);

    angular.extend(contentFactory, {
      example: function() {
        $window.alert('extended service: ' + contentFactory.title);
      }
    });

    return contentFactory;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainController as ctrl">
  <h3>
    click image to test extended content class
    </h3>
  <img ng-src="{{ctrl.newImage.src}}" ng-click="ctrl.newImage.example()" />
  <p>
    {{ctrl.newImage.title}}
  </p>
</div>
```